# Store Lists: Automate Copy and Pasting in VBA

Tags: vba, copy, store, paste

I am fairly new to using VBA and I think my problem is both pretty common and simple to figure out for experts. I greatly appreciate all of the help.

I have 2 sheets in excel.

1. The first is everything in the store. All of the items are there and all we use it for is to write in a quantity next to the item (sometimes items are added to the list either by inserting a new row or adding it to the bottom). We have a formula that adds up the costs next to each item (and that works fine).
2. The second sheet is our shopping list. After we input the quantity next to our list of products, we go through the list and write the quantity and product name in a grocery list in another sheet.

**I am trying to automate the list writing process by running a macro that scans the quantity column in our store list, and copies and pastes the quantity and product name on the sheet with our grocery list.**

```
Sub Proposal()
  ' Estimating_Proposal Macro
  ' make the quantity an integer 
  Dim Quantity As Integer

  StoreList.Range(Cells(H6)) = Quantity

  Sheets("StoreList").Select
  Range("G6").Select

  ' have the while loop end when there is not more information in the column

  While quantity. = Value
    Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
    Sheets("StoreList").Select
    Range("C4").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21

    If Quantity Is Nothing Then
      Sheets("StoreList").Select

      Copy and paste values of the products with 1 or more as the quantity.
    End If

    Range("C3").Select
```

Comment: Filter on the quantity column the copy the visisble cells and past the values on the next page.  Or use Advanced Filter.

Comment: how do you use advanced filter? we are trying to make it automatic.

Comment: http://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/